# How to have shared read-only access to a memory mapped file

Tags: c#, .net, memory-mapped-files

While using a memory mapped file to read in a filestream as fast as possible in .net, I ran into the issue of `IOException`s due to file locking with two processes reading the same file.

There are several factory methods for producing a memory mapped file, how do I allow shared `readonly` access?

Comment: Memory-mapped files are likely not the fastest option available. Streaming with `SequentialScan` is the fastest way to read files.

Comment: Well what I'm personally using is passing it to a parser for a binary format that doesn't necessarily read the entire file, so not having the overhead of seeking seems like it would win, I've not tried sequential scan, but for my purposes, the memory mapped file vs a plain readonly filestream was orders of magnitude faster.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a simplified factory method for creating a readonly memory mapped file to a path:

```
public static MemoryMappedFile MemFile(string path)
{
     return MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile(
               //include a readonly shared stream
               File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read),
               //not mapping to a name
               null,
               //use the file's actual size
               0L, 
               //read only access
               MemoryMappedFileAccess.Read, 
               //not configuring security
               null,
               //adjust as needed
               HandleInheritability.None,
               //close the previously passed in stream when done
               false);

}
```

To create and use the full stream:

```
using (var memFile = MemFile(path))
using (var stream = memFile.CreateViewStream(0L, 0L, MemoryMappedFileAccess.Read))
{
     //do stuff with your stream
}
```